# How to arrange an array to saveAll in CakePHP?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array, cakephp-2.6

It's a little complicated to explain the way that I got the data from the view, but it arrives correctly to the controller.

I have `3 models`: `TourOpcione` (this always save only one record), and `TourOpcionOficina` and `TourOpcionServicio` (these can save one or more records at time, and they have a `foreign key` to `TourOpcione`).

My problem is that I don't know what's the correct way to arrange the data in my controller before to save that. I want to avoid to use a loop, so I wish to save it with `saveAll`, or `saveAssociated`, or if this is not the case, accept any other way.
The explains around internet are confused.
I'm using `CakePHP 2.6`

Actually this is the array that I had created:

```
array
(
[TourOpcione] => Array
    (
        [opcion] => 1
        [numeroPersonas] => 4
        [total] => 2038
        [tour_prospecto_id] => 12
    )

[TourOpcionOficina] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [oficina_id] => 1623
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [oficina_id] => 1624
            )
    )

[TourOpcionServicio] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [servicio_id] => 6068
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [servicio_id] => 6067
            )
    )
)
```

Thanks in advice.

**UPDATE**

At this point, the `TourOpcione` is the only model who save the data. The other 2 doesn't. 
Where can be my problem? 
My models are the next (each class in his own model):

```
class tour_opcione extends AppModel {

public $name = 'TourOpcione';
public $hasMany = array(
    'TourOpcionServicio' => array(
        'className' => 'TourOpcionServicio',
        'foreignKey' => 'tour_opcione_id',
    ),
    'TourOpcionOficina' => array(
        'className' => 'TourOpcionOficina',
        'foreignKey' => 'tour_opcione_id',
    )
);
}

class tour_opcion_servicio extends AppModel {

public $name = 'TourOpcionServicio';
public $belongsTo = array(
    'TourOpcione' => array(
        'className' => 'TourOpcione',
        'foreignKey' => 'tour_opcione_id'
    )
);
}

class tour_opcion_oficina extends AppModel {

public $name = 'TourOpcionOficina';
public $belongsTo = array(
    'TourOpcione' => array(
        'className' => 'TourOpcione',
        'foreignKey' => 'tour_opcione_id'
    )
);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array There are several examples and one is quite the same like your problem (see at: And for saving a record along with its related records having hasMany with more than two levels deep associations, the data array should be as follow:=

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't working.

Comment: @iglesiasedd what does your save call look like? Are you using `saveAssociated()` or `saveAll()` to save the data?

Comment: I had use both of them, and only save the `TourOpcione` model

Comment: Also using `array('deep' => true)`.
But nothing.

Comment: @iglesiasedd check to see if there were any validation errors after save: `debug($this->TourOpcione->validationErrors)`

Comment: @antoniovassell Exactly what does `validationErrors`?

Comment: @iglesiasedd It shows you the validation errors if there is any: `if ($this->Recipe->save($this->request->data)) {
    // handle the success.
}
debug($this->Recipe->validationErrors);`

Comment: @iglesiasedd http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html#validating-data-from-the-controller just do this to check if there may have been any validation errors that prevented failure